# SVG <g> Group Style, Attributes etc

Tags: javascript, svg, ecmascript-6

I am animating some SVG objects that I have created using Javascript and setting the X and Y attributes of my objects using 'setAttributeNS'.

I have also put objects in groups with other objects and have set stroke, fills etc using `<g>` tags group =

```js
e.g1 = document.createElementNS(svg, "g" );
e.g1.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke", "#000"); //eye inherits this//
e.g1.setAttributeNS(null,"cy", e.y); //currently not being inherited in group..//
   
e.eye = document.createElementNS(svg, "ellipse");
e.eye.setAttributeNS(null,"cx", e.x);
e.eye.setAttributeNS(null,"cy", e.y); //I want to set this from group so i can remove this line from all objects on the groups y axis//
document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(e.eye);


e.g1.appendChild (e.eye);
```

This is working brilliant for styles, but is there any way to share attributes such as X and Y value so all svg objects set there Y axis from the group they are in, unless they have been assigned there own Y axis (just like how the styles work).

Thanks

Comment: set a transform e.g. transform="translate(10,10)" but that will apply to all contents, x, y, cx, cy can provide additional changes if necessary.

Comment: This eventually worked but broke a few other transforms on the objects I set individually, do you know of any way to apply transformations on objects which have already been transformed (without over-writing the transform tag), I think when I apply a transform rotation on objects within the group they somehow forget about the translate.

What first comes to mind is just applying the Y translation in the same transform tag before the rotation, but seems like long way around. So does creating additional groups.  I guess I have to do one or the other?

Comment: nest the `<g>` elements and apply the transforms you want to them one at a time in the nest